# Extracting machine data using Pi

Tags: pi-3b+

We currently have moulding machines i am looking at whether i can use raspberry pi to give live data from each machine either from the main control board or the traffic lights system we have to show us the machines condition, Red - major issue, Yellow, intermittent issue, green - running.

Thanks

Dale

Comment: Hello. Can you fill out your question a little with more details on the moulding machines you use such as what interfaces they have for extracting data and if you know what protocols they may use. Without that information is going to be difficult to give any sort of answer other than "probably".

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) But please write proper sentences so it is better readable. And please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.